# I am trying to display upcoming shows from a database using jinja template . The codes are seen below

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

```py
class Venue(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'venue'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    city = db.Column(db.String(120))
    state = db.Column(db.String(120))
    address = db.Column(db.String(120))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(120))
    genres = db.Column(db.String(120))
    image_link = db.Column(db.String(500))
    facebook_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
    website_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
    seeking_talent = db.Column(db.String(120))
    seeking_description = db.Column(db.String(120))
    shows = db.relationship(
      'Shows', backref='venue', lazy='joined', cascade='all, delete')

    # TODO: implement any missing fields, as a database migration using Flask-Migrate


class Artist(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'artist'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    city = db.Column(db.String(120))
    state = db.Column(db.String(120))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(120))
    genres = db.Column(db.String(120))
    image_link = db.Column(db.String(500))
    facebook_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
    website_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
    Seeking_venue = db.Column(db.String(120))
    Seeking_description = db.Column(db.String(120))
    shows = db.relationship(
      'Shows', backref='artist', lazy='joined', cascade='all, delete')

    # TODO: implement any missing fields, as a database migration using Flask-Migrate


class Shows(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'shows'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    artist_id= db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('artist.id'), nullable = False)
    venue_id= db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('venue.id'), nullable = False)
    start_time = db.Column(db.String(120))
   



@app.route('/artists/<int:artist_id>')
def show_artist(artist_id):
  artist=Artist.query.join(Shows).filter(Artist.id==artist_id)
  r=db.session.query(Venue,Artist, Shows).join(Shows, Artist.id==Shows.artist_id).all()
  for r in r:
    upcoming_show= Shows.start_time>datetime.now()
    if upcoming_show==True:
      r
  return render_template('pages/show_artist.html', artist=artist, r=r, upcoming_show=upcoming_show)
```

This is the template:

```html
<section>
    <h2 class="monospace">{{ artist.upcoming_shows_count }} Upcoming {% if artist.upcoming_shows_count == 1 %}Show{% else %}Shows{% endif %}</h2>
    <div class="row">
        {%for r in r %}{%if upcoming_show==True%}
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="tile tile-show">
                <img src="{{ r.Venue.image_link }}" alt="Show Venue Image" />
                <h5><a href="/venues/{{ r.Shows.venue_id }}">{{ r.Shows.venue_name }}</a></h5>
                <h6>{{ r.Shows.start_time|datetime('full') }}</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        {%endif%} {% endfor %}
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please try to explain better so we can understand, here is a link that talks about asking good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the data type associated with `DateTime` to store a timestamp in the database. In the following I use a time specification as UTC. This is common and makes it easier to deal with users' different time zones. You can use [flask-moment](https://flask-moment.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to display the time in the user specific time zone.

```py
from datetime import datetime 

class Show(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    artist_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('artist.id'), nullable = False)
    venue_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('venue.id'), nullable = False)
    start_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
```

The actual query of the upcoming shows can be easily realized within one request. You can query all shows whose `artist_id` matches and whose start time is greater than or equal to the current time.

```py
@app.route('/artists/<int:artist_id>')
def show_artist(artist_id):
    artist = Artist.query.get_or_404(artist_id)
    shows = Show.query\
        .filter(Show.artist_id == artist_id, Show.start_time >= datetime.utcnow())\
        .order_by(Show.start_time)\
        .all()
    return render_template('pages/show_artist.html', **locals())
```

Now it is only necessary to output the found shows in the jinja template.

```html
<section>
  {% set count = shows | count -%}
  <h2 class="monospace">{{ count }} Upcoming {{ ('Show', 'Shows')[count > 1]}}</h2>
  <div class="row">
    {% for show in shows -%}
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="tile tile-show">
        <img src="{{ show.venue.image_link }}" alt="Show Venue Image" />
        <h5><a href="{{ url_for('show_venue', venue_id=show.venue.id) }}">{{ show.venue.name }}</a></h5>
        <h6>{{ show.start_time|datetime('full') }}</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor -%}
  </div>
</section>
```